# Not null property value search in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I want to search documents from the query console based on some property which is not null. Lets say this is the json documents i have.

> { "a1" : "1234", "a2" : "abc", "a3" : null, "a4" : "mno" }
>
> { "a1" : "1235", "a2" : "xyz", "a3" : "value", "a4" : "mno" }

I can query documents based on property like this

```
cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:json-property-value-query("a3","value"));
```

I am not able to use **not equal logical operator** with this query. Can anybody let me know, if i have to search documents based on property **a3** which is not null then what has to be the query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just value-queries, I would do it like this:

```
cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:and-query(
            (
            cts:json-property-value-query("a3", "*", "wildcarded"),
            cts:not-query(cts:json-property-value-query("a3", json:null()))
            )
           ) 
      );
```

I could have affected this with a smaller query by using a word-query instead of a value query.

Note that the use of the wildcarded query was just to isolate candidate documents that had the element 'a3'. For XML, I would have used an element-query to make sure I had the element, but I do not know of any way to do that in json directly.

Comment: What would the equivalent of this query using ServerSide JavaScript?

Comment: I do not have that answer - but I would think Query builder should be able to build the above. Note: This is a new question and will be lost in the comments. I suggest you open a new ticket and ask the question there.